# How to set recognition area in Android Vision API?

Tags: java, android, barcode

How to set the camera recognition area in only one place?

I want to set barcode recognition only for region 1.
I have created an area in which the bar code will arrive, and I want to make a definition only in this part of the screen. And now my bar code is recognized all over the screen area. How to fix it?

[api example link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evBH9.png)

Comment: The vision api does not have a way of defining areas, if you look at their example they choose the closest barcode to where the user clicked on the screen

Comment: You could probably used the bounding box that gets returned for each barcode read and check to see if it is inside you "area's" bounding box

Comment: @tyczj
mabe you have an example?

Comment: No i dont but just look at the source code of the example where they find the barcode and you can figure it out